# Are nested conditionals possible in Zendesk?

Tags: zendesk

We're currently trying to set up a more streamlined ticketing system, to help organize tasks, according to not only groups, but also individual users within those groups.

I am using the conditionals app in Zendesk, and I am curious as to whether or not certain ticket fields can be applied to specific assignees within distinct groups.

So currently we have 3 groups, and depending on the group chosen the ticket form populates with different fields. My question is whether or not I can nest ANOTHER conditional once a group is chosen to give certain users within that group different form fields.

Any help appreiciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to use the following method to make nested choices, and this works with the conditional fields app also
https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203661876-Organizing-drop-down-list-options

I used this to create options for the Lens type e.g. and applied it to only the Cannon lens, and then when you select a Canon camera type the lens field shows up

[Example Conditional Fields screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrZJV.png)